# What is wrong here? Expected expression before '=' token?

Tags: c

I am trying to set up a structure in the C program I am writing.  However, the compiler returns that it is expecting an expression before the '=' token on line 31.  Below is a snippet of the code containing the struct and the line of code in question:
EDIT: THREAD_COUNT was defined to be

```
#define THREAD_COUNT = 120

struct threadInfo
{
    int threadId;
};

struct threadInfo customerIDs[THREAD_COUNT]; //offending line here
```

I have tried chaning it into an expression with an = sign, I tried changing the way the struct was declared, but nothing has worked so far.  Any advice?
EDIT 2: The error was resolved.  My definition of THREAD_COUNT was incorrect.

Comment: It looks like your definition of `THREAD_COUNT` contains an `=`. The code you've shown is incomplete, but given a reasonable definition for `THREAD_COUNT`, it will compile fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show how you've defined `THREAD_COUNT`.

Comment: ^^ e.g. #define THREAD_COUNT=1 rather than proper #define THREAD_COUNT 1

Comment: Thank you guys.  The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `=` in your `#define` statement. It should be:

```
#define THREAD_COUNT 120
```

Preprocessor definitions aren't variables, they just do simple text replacement.